# How do i make my button link to the next page without changing the styling?

Tags: html, css

How do i make my button link to the next page without changing the styling?

```
  <div class="image-round-fit">

    <img src="images/pic.jpg" alt="photo" width="300px" height="300px" />

    <span class="caption">Hello World</span></br>

      <a href="#" class="btn btn-info role=button">Click Next</a>

  </div>
```

Comment: What you are trying to archive? What you expected as result?

Comment: I am trying to make the button click and direct to the next page.

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't understand what you want to do?

Comment: Are you trying not to change the style of the button or the page?

Comment: He means that whenever you click the link and then go back to the website where you clicked the link, then it is purple. He wants it blue, just like the original one

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS to do it. CSS is a language to style content in HTML.

```css
a{
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href = "#" class = "btn btn-info" role = "button">Click Next</a>
```

The a is the tag name it is relating to. The color and text-decoration are properties. The color changes the text color and the text-decoration changes extras to the text, including if you want to include underline or not.

Or maybe it was this? To not change the color to purple permanently.

```css
a:visited{
    color: blue;
}
a:active{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href = "#" role = "button" class = "btn btn-info">Click Next</a>
```

The : stands for it relating to the a when in a condition. :visited stands for when you visited it, it will do whatever below. :active does whatever below when your mouse is down on the link. Remove the :active if you don't want it to change color at any state.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have `role=button` inside your class. It should be outside your class as an attribute :

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Click Next</a>
```

This is for assistive technologies and button element should be used instead when possible.